# Laravel sending emails to multiple users takes too long

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

I'm looking for a solution how can I optimize my code to send email to all users in my app?

```
    $emails = [
        'myoneemail@esomething.com',
        'myoneemail@esomething.com',
        'myoneemail@esomething.com',
        ...
    ];

    $data = [
        'subject' => 'Items List',
        'mailFrom' => 'no-replay@example.com',
        'items' => $items
    ];

    foreach ($emails as $email) {

        Mail::to($email)->queue(new Mailable($data));

    }
    return back();
```

Is there are any solution to optimize it? In the live app I have more than 100 users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you can use the `Mail::bcc($emails)->queue(new Mailable($data));`.
That way you can just send 1 mail, with all the emails in BCC.

However if every mail is different/customised to the users, you might want to check how to dispatch the email event from a job (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#creating-jobs).

Comment: Using queue-able jobs, you'll be able to trigger the job and let in run in the background. You/the user/etc will be able to leave it and it'll process through in time.

Comment: But in this case filed TO:  in the mailbox will look like this <>. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I don't think there is...Other solution is to create a job that you push on a queue. Like Will explained in the comment above, it is a way to send the mails but not wait for the response.